# How to estimate minimum sample size for distance measuring when sigma is known?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, sample-size

If I have a distance probe with a known standard deviation of 0.007mm (σ) and normal distribution and I want to caculate how many samples I need to take to ensure that the mean of my samples is in 99.9% (z=3.09) of cases within 0.01mm (ε) of µ.

Is this correct?

n >= (z * σ / ε )²

Comment: You could make an expression for the variance of the mean of a sample of size $n$, let's call it $\sigma_n$, and use the condition $$\sigma_n \cdot z \leq \epsilon$$ I let you figure out the expression for $\sigma_n$ and see whether your result is correct. But note, it might not be correct to assume a standard deviation for the error of the distance probe. And even when that assumption is true, then you have to think about the potential dependence between measurements of the individuals in the sample.

Comment: In addition, what is $\mu$?